# How do I fix Metaboss Update Error 0x6c when trying to upgrade creator?

Tags: anchor, solana, metaboss

trying to upgrade metadata for an NFT collection. However im getting this error code and cant figure what it means:

Action failed with error: RPC response error -32002: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x6c [5 log messages]"

I upgraded another collection with another upgrade authority before and worked like a charme. for this oen where its failing I also checked to have 2 SOL on the wallet and if its the correct keypair

thank you in advance!

I upgraded another collection with another upgrade authority before and worked like a charme. for this oen where its failing I also checked to have 2 SOL on the wallet and if its the correct keypair